# Are EDA Software Questions Off Topic

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Are questions about the use and operation of EE software off topic, when those questions have no EE background at all?

e.g.

- Convergence,
- Compilation,
- Bugs.

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to post software questions keep in mind:

1. As with any question, the problem and\or question should be well documented, and conform to site guidelines.
2. You should consider the likelihood of getting your question answered. If no one uses the software or the software is kind of obscure, then its probably better to find a different site. If there isn't a tag for your software, that would be the first indication that there might not be anybody that can answer your question.
3. Some questions are better posed to the manufacturers of the software and their support systems.
4. Bugs are probably better directed at the manufacturer, as they would be the ones that could fix the problem

Spice questions probably take the lead lead of questions for software, some cad packages are also popular with many users like Altium, Eagle, KiCad.

Answer (score 2):

Questions about the *use and operation* of EE software are absolutely on-topic. What you have listed are not *"use and operation"*.

What you have listed should be directed to the respective software package support system.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your question is on topic if it is about:

- Writing firmware for a bare metal or RTOS microcontroller.
- Digital logic/PLD/FPGA design, VHDL, Verilog etc.
- PLC programming.
- Specific tools necessary for any of the above.

It is not on-topic if it is a general programming question not specific to any of the above. Such questions should be asked at https://stackoverflow.com instead.